# Passing an object as a parameter of an overloaded operator+ in a template class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, class-template

I'm trying to pass an object as a parameter of an overloaded operator+ (and the class is a template class) but it's giving me an error which states:

```
error C2955: 'Kvader': use of class template requires template argument list
```

this is my class:

```
template <class Q>
class Kvader {
private:
    Q a, b, c;
public:
    Kvader(const Kvader &temp);
    Kvader operator+(Kvader);
};
```

and this is my overloaded+ method:

```
template <class Q>
Kvader Kvader<Q>::operator+(Kvader<int> temp) {
a += temp.a;
b += temp.b;
c += temp.c;
return *this;
}
```

I thought that

```
Kvader Kvader<Q>::operator+(Kvader<int> temp)
```

would suffice as the argument list. What am I doing wrong?

In my main i'm just making 2 objects, (the second one calls the copy constructor) and then I try to add them together.

```
int main(){
Kvader<int> object1, object2(object1);
object1 = object1 + object2;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a template argument in the return type. As a guess, `Kvader<Q> Kvader<Q>::operator+(Kvader<int> temp) ...`

Comment: Argument in `operator+` should be `const&` and its return type should be a reference like so: `Kvader<Q>& Kvader<Q>::operator+(const Kvader<Q>& temp)`. Addtionally you mix specializing (for `int`s) and defininig templates.

Comment: @Patryk `operator +=` should return a reference, not `operator +`.

Comment: @JemCpp Sorry my mistake I have missed that detail. It should be indeed `Kvader<Q> Kvader<Q>::operator+(const Kvader<Q>& temp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code contains a few errors:

1) `Kvader<Q> Kvader<Q>::operator+(Kvader<int> temp)`

You need to specify the argument list for the return type as well.

2) `Kvader<Q> operator+(Kvader<int>);`

Same as 1) + change the argument type to `Kvader<int>` instead of the generic `Kvader<Q>`.

3) `Kvader<Q>(const Kvader<Q> &temp);`

Same as 1).

4) Specify a default constructor for `Kvader<Q>` else the creation statement in `main()` is going to fail.

5) Also, `operator+(const T&)` should return a reference to allow for operator chaining. It also typically takes a const reference to avoid unnecessary copying.

6) Finally, unless you have a particular reason for doing it the way you've done it, things like `operator+(const Kvader<Q>&)` should be defined in a generic fashion first, and then be specialized, when there is a need to do so. The way you've written it, `operator+(cont Kvader<int>&)` only works for those types where the `Q` type of the `this` object can be added to an `int`. What you probably wanted to achieve, was to enable a specialization of `Kvader` with any certain parameter to be added to `Kvader`'s with the same exact parameter. Then, you can create specializations for specific `Q` types, such as `int`.

I suggest you actually read up on class and function templates! They can be confusing at times, indeed.

Complete code:

```
template <class Q>
class Kvader {
private:
    Q a, b, c;
public:
    Kvader() {}
    Kvader(const Kvader<Q> &temp);
    Kvader& operator+(const Kvader<Q>& temp);
};

template <class Q>
Kvader<Q>& Kvader<Q>::operator+(const Kvader<Q>& temp) {
a += temp.a;
b += temp.b;
c += temp.c;
return *this;
}

template<class Q>
Kvader<Q>::Kvader(const Kvader<Q> &temp)
{}

int main(){
Kvader<int> object1, object2(object1);
object1 = object1 + object2;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<Q>` is not required inside `class Kvader { ... };`, it's implicit.

Comment: I'm not an expert, not at all, but cpp.sh, which uses gcc 4.9 as the backend, accepts that code. Thank you for the hint! I'll check Josuttis' book.